# Bad compatibility of MuMin with multinom (nnet) objects having 3 level response variables?

Tags: r, statistics, regression, multinomial, nnet

I face a problem when trying to use the function `model.avg` of the `MuMin` package on objects resulting from the function `multinom` (package `nnet`). 
Although the manual list as `multinom` compatible, the `model.avg` function doesn't return the model average coefficients for the explanatory variables as I expect.

I know that the problem doesn't exist when the `multinom` reponse variable as 2 levels only, so I guess it depends on the structure of the resulting multinom object. However, I don't know how to fix this issue.

Here is an example code where the function `model.avg` works as expected:

```
#### MuMIn example  
library(MuMIn)  
data(Cement)  
fm1 <- lm(y ~ ., data = Cement)  
dd <- dredge(fm1)  
summary(model.avg(dd, subset = delta < 4))$coefmat
```

Results:

```
               Estimate Std. Error Adjusted SE   z value  Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) 64.69312754 22.2354794  22.4624137 2.8800613 0.0039760
X1           1.45579791  0.2036676   0.2193043 6.6382554 0.0000000
X2           0.62502598  0.1202570   0.1291705 4.8387682 0.0000013
X4          -0.47600710  0.2215167   0.2309395 2.0611767 0.0392862
X3          -0.02153196  0.3767120   0.3924356 0.0548675 0.9562440
```

In this case, the 'model.avg' function returns the `Model-averaged coefficients` (column `Estimate`) for the explanatory variables (i.e. X1-X4) as expected.

Now, if I want to apply this to a `multinom` object (response variable with at least 3 levels):

```
#### application to multinomial regression
library(foreign) ; library(nnet) ; library(MuMIn)
ml <- read.dta("http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsbdemo.dta")
ml$prog2 <- relevel(ml$prog, ref = "academic")
test <- multinom(prog2 ~ ses + write + schtyp, data = ml)
# [...] verbosity not displayed here
dd <- dredge(test)
# [...] verbosity not displayed here
summary(model.avg(dd, subset = delta < 4))$coefmat
```

Results

```
         Estimate Std. Error  z value    Pr(>|z|)
general  2.850316   1.169132 2.437977 0.014769732
vocation 5.134921   1.173878 4.374322 0.000012181
```

Here, the function returns "model average coefficients" for the different levels of the response variable (i.e. `general` and `vocation`) rather than for the model average coefficients for the explanatory variables.

If this is possible, could you tell me please how to get the `Model average coefficients` for the explanatory variables from `multinom` objects?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was indeed a bug with extraction of coefficients from multinom objects. It is fixed now in MuMIn 1.9.13.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, I came back lately but it's still useful :)